# Potential problems in updating openSSH from 5.3p1 to 5.7p1 or 7.7p1(latest stable)

Tags: linux, ssh, openssh, scp

I have 3 [Red Hat 6.6](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/6.6_release_notes/index) servers with openSSH version [5.3p1](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-5.3) I require use of the `scp -3` option which was not introduced until [5.7p1](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-5.7).

Ideally, I would like to upgrade to openSSH [7.7p1](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-7.7) which is the latest stable version.

The problem is that there are many legacy processes making many ssh calls. Some of these run several times hourly, some may run monthly. I need a way to know that upgrading openSSH will not break anything without examining every legacy process. All I know about the legacy processes is that none of them are failing due to openSSH right now.

My current method is to scour the [release notes](https://www.openssh.com/releasenotes.html) for deprecated features and syntax that could possibly have been dropped between versions. This is doable between 5.3p1 and 5.7p1 but I feel as though I may have missed something. I do not think I will be able to foresee all possible problems between 5.3p1 and the current stable version due to the sheer number of changes made.

Is there a general method that I can employee to see if it is safe to upgrade from an old version of a software to a new one? Are there specific changes in openSSH that I need to be aware of?

Comment: The best method is to set up a test environment and test the versions before implementing in production. When upgrading, while the biggest concern is usually whether the features you require function in a workable way, there are also other concerns, such as the method and reliability of the upgrade process, and the need to do basic use cases to hopefully catch unforeseen issues. You can also look for people who have performed this upgrade themselves who have similar requirements.

Comment: IME newer OpenSSH almost never removes _syntax_, but fairly often does remove or restrict security algorithms (e.g.RC4, DSA) that in the past were considered acceptable and may still be in use on your servers. I would test _first_ doing transport connection from commandline to all servers; if you don't know all the hosts, either monitor the traffic, or use `known_hosts` as the list of hosts that probably have been used more or less recently.